# Volume of PGL(2,F) \ PGL(2, A)

Tags: nt.number-theory, reductive-groups, adeles, automorphic-forms, reference-request

Let $F$ be a global field. What is the measure of $PGL_2(F) \backslash PGL_2(\mathbb{A})$?

This depends of course on the normalizations of the Haar measures on $PGL_2(F)$ and $PGL_2(\mathbb{A})$. Probably its most likely available in the literature for $PGL_2(F)$ admits the discrete measure and $PGL_2(\mathbb{A})$ the Tamagawa measure, but I couldn't find!?

I remember that there was a question about the measure of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ here in the past, but couldn't find it.

It should be related to special values of the Dedekind zeta function.

Comment: This should be in Weil's *Adeles and algebraic groups*, chapter 3.

Comment: A _natural_ measure gives that quotient measure essentially $\zeta_F(2)$. The renormalization as in Siegel, Weil and elsewhere will make it $1$ or a power of $2$, probably, as usual. For $PGL_n$, it's similarly $\zeta_F(2)\zeta_F(3)...\zeta_F(n)$. A classical argument over $\mathbb Q$ (which obviously generalizes), also for $Sp(n)$, is at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/volumes.pdf

Comment: As I expected it to be. @ACL: I'll check tomorrow. @P.Garrett: Sweet notes. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the Tamagawa number is 1. http://books.google.com/books?id=yrmT56mpw3kC&lpg=PA246&dq=tamagawa%20number%207.6.3&pg=PA246#v=onepage&q=tamagawa%20number%207.6.3&f=false

Comment: @Agol: The basic conjecture, which has been proved for all simple types, assumes a *simply connected* group here.   Clozel has a useful Sem. Bourbaki expose 702, following the work by Kottwitz and others/

Comment: Another way to choose a "natural" normalization is by looking at the residue of the leading pole of minimal-parabolic spherical Eisenstein series, which is a constant that does not depend on choices of measure.

Comment: @Agol: The Tamagawa number is 1 for the special linear group. For the projective linear group, which is isogeneous to the special linear group, it is some rational number (whom I do not remember).

Comment: @Paul Garrett: I am confused. Up to a rational number, the measure of the arithmetic quotient $SL_n(\mathbf R)/SL_n(\mathbf Z)$ is a product of zeta values  for every reasonable normalization. What is equal to 1, is the measure of the adelic quotient $SL_n(\mathbf A)/SL_n(\mathbf Q)$ - once the Haar measure is suitably normalized.

Comment: @ACL: I'm not saying anything that's not well known, but, at the same time, it is exactly the question of "normalization" that one might address. Yes, there is a prescription (e.g., as in Weil) to get the adele quotient to have measure 1 (or 2, etc), but if we didn't already know the answer, we might not manage to make that normalization. E.g., it is not obvious that one should go the route Weil took, getting measures from invariant differential forms everywhere locally, and so on. But if someone else likes that prescription, I don't object! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take the Tamagawa measure, the measure is 2. It is equal to the index of the universal covering, so for a simply connected group $G$ the volue of $G({\mathbb A})/G(F)$ is one. This is Kottwitz's Theorem, formerly known as the Tamagawa number conjecture. A proof is in
http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2007007?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21101828946301

Comment: Okay, I was interested more in the measure, which enters directly into dimension formulas of modular forms. But after all, your answer is correct and I actually was aware of Kottwitz's achievement.  Thank you nevertheless. It seems that the normalisation enters by giving the maximal compact groups some non-unit normalization as in Gelbart-Jacquet. Thanks.

Comment: Oesterle's 1984 Inventiones paper on Tamagawa numbers (see Inv. Math. 78) has a very elegant discussion of the normalization issues to define the Tamagawa measure and Tamagawa number for rather general smooth connected affine groups over global fields. His normalizations are *not* governed by maximal compact subgroups (as they ought not be, since typically there are a lot of non-conjugate such subgroups!). He also cleaned up some points of possible confusion that arose in earlier work by others in the case of tori.